# how to analyze performance and memory leaks in code

Tags: java

How to improve the performance of below code ,Can you please provide any hints to improve the code performance is it correct way to use CopyOnWriteList .Is there any chance below code could cause memory leaks.

code:

```
public static List<TestVO> description(final TestVO desc) {

    List<TestVO> descList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<TestVO>();

    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String add = "";
    TestVO desc =null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        desc = new TestVO();
        for (String key : audit.getLog().keySet()) {
            if (!key.equals("hello")) {
                builder.append(key + "=" + audit.getLog().get(key)
                        + add);
                add = ", ";
                audit.getLog().remove(key);
            } else {
                desc.setDesc(key + " = "
                        + audit.getLog().get(key));
                descList.add(desc);
                audit.getLog().remove(key);
                break;
            }

        }

    }
    desc.setDesc("Checks : " + builder.toString());
    descList.add(desc);
    return descList;

}
```

Calling from main method:

```
              TestVO a1=new TestVO();
    a1.getLog().put("1", new BigDecimal(12));
    a1.getLog().put("2", new BigDecimal(22));
    a1.getLog().put("3", new BigDecimal(32));
    a1.getLog().put("4", new BigDecimal(42));
    a1.getLog().put("Hello", new BigDecimal(90));

    description(a1);
```

TestVO has 2 methods one is log its type is HashMap and other one is desc its type is string.

Comment: Sorry, what's the question? And pick just one.

Comment: soory haylem, question is about:is there anyway to improve the above code performance and did you find any memory leaks.if so,how to identify

Comment: Your code makes no sense. It will throw null pointer exceptions because you re-declare the inpout parameter `desc` with the line `TestVO desc =null;`, and then you dereference that null-value `desc` later. Also, you have an un-declared value `auditDesc` which makes no sense. Post your **actual** code!

Comment: Do a google search for java profilers.

Comment: @user2680017 That's three questions. "Can I improve performance of the above code?" (Yes, you probably can.) "Did you find any memory leaks?" (No but I also didn't bother looking, SO is not an organic debugger.) "How to identify them?" (Run your code over a realistic dataset and see if the memory usage grows out of bounds when it shouldn't.)

Comment: @user2680017: I'd reply I'm not a seer nor a wizard, and I forgot my crystal ball at home anyways.

Comment: All in all, without a more complete code example and more specific question, this looks like a better fit for [codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)... Maybe you should take it over to them.

Answer (score 1):

## Performance Tips for That Particular Code

- Lose the seemingly useless first loop.
- Use `StringBuilder` the way it's meant to be:

  ```
  builder.append(key + "=" + audit.getLog().get(key) + add);
  ```

  Should really be:

  ```
  builder.append(key).append("=").append(audit.getLog().get(key)).append(add);
  ```
- Do you really need a descList as a `List` and not a `Set`?
- You don't need a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` here anyways. Or at Least we can't know if you need one from this code.

## General Tips for That Particular Code

- It's very unclear what that does, it looks like a made up and contrived example. Is it one?
- Your code seems to make multiple things at once. Maybe it's good for performance, but maybe that also gives it a pretty weird design.
- The way you change your `add` variable seems rather odd and it looks like you'd be better off building a collection and then generating the strings you need.
- `auditDesc` is undeclared, so you probably didn't give us the correct code.
- <strike>you say `calling from main method`, but we don't see any calls to `description()`</strike> <sup>(Found it, wasn't visible as it was outside of the code block.)</sup>
- We have no clue what it's supposed to do, so I can't really be of more help until your provide a more complete code sample.

Comment: Thanks haylem, I gave complete code and working fine.how to improve the code

Comment: First loop is to write 2 entries into list

Comment: Multiple threads call this code that is the reason I used copyonwritearralist here.what is your suggestion to chsnge the design of code

Comment: Add variable to add , after each entry.what is your suggested way.did you any chance of memory lekage

Comment: I don't think handling multiple threads and memory leakage are your biggest problems at this point.

Comment: @user2680017: it's not in the code itself or in specific areas, it's that you need to practice a lot more. Seems early to focus on particular problems like multi-threading when there seems to be other issues to address first, notably design and reading comprehension (we asked you for the full code, and for what the code is supposed to be doing).